# Show row index column in a jQuery Row Reordering DataTable with dynamic row adding

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, row, html-table

I've looked at [this example](http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html) in which you can see that row index is being shown and also updated dynamically as the user moves the rows around - which is exactly the desired behaviour in my case.

However, in that example the table in generated through static HTML code. I'm using the `row.add()` method from the DataTable api.

For simplicity's sake I'll show you an example where I am adding rows through a simple for-loop.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="../css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js"> </script>
  <script>
  $(function() {

     $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display cell-border"  id="example" ></table>');

        t = $('#example').dataTable({
            "columns": 
            [
                {"title": "Action", "data": "action" },
            ],
        }).rowReordering();;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
        {
            t.api().row.add(
            {
                action: 'action'+String(i),
            }).draw();
        }    

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So the question is: How can I show row numbers in my table that are being updated whenever the user moves a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUSE**

Original [Row Reordering add-on](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering) is incompatible with DataTables 1.10.

**SOLUTION**

I have [forked the add-on on github](https://github.com/mpryvkin/jquery-datatables-row-reordering) and added support for DataTables 1.10
by using suggestions in the [comments](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/Index) by *legrand....@gmail.com*.

Table should have a proper structure, below is an excerpt from the [manual](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/RowReordering):

> - Table must be properly formatted according to the DataTables requirements e.g. it must have `THEAD`, `TBODY` and optionally `TFOOT` sections
> - Each `TR` element must have `id` attribute.
> - One column in the table should be indexing column. This column will be used for determining position of the row in the table. By default this is first column in the table.

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
         $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
      }    
   });

   for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
      table.row.add([ 
         i,
         i + '.2',
         i + '.3',
         i + '.4',
         i + '.5',
         i + '.6'
      ]);
   }  

   table.draw();

   table.rowReordering();
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>jQuery DataTables</title>  
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mpryvkin/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/95b44786cb41cf37bd3ad39e39e1d216277bd727/media/js/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Start date</th>
  <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Start date</th>
  <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Row Reordering doesn't seem to work in your example?

Comment: @user3262713, corrected link to modified add-on, try now.